# Can Namespace level permissions be set with Google Cloud IAM on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubernetes [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) can be used to give permissions to a subject in a particular Namespace. Can the same be accomplished with Cloud IAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, no. IAM is used to assign and verify permissions when interacting with GCP APIs. IAM can only provide access to the GKE API, which does not take into account namespaces.

As you mentioned, RBAC is your option for more granular permissions within the cluster

Comment: well there does seem to be some control over API access, the predefined roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#roles) suggest that Cloud IAM can influence Kubernetes API access?

Comment: in a sense yes, but IAM does not get very fine grained on any level and does not  fully control interaction with the kubernetes API

Comment: Is there any way of exposing Cloud IAM groups to be used in RBAC rules?

Comment: [Not at the moment, no](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#assigning_permissions_to_users_with_rolebinding). You can only assign IAM permissions to IAM groups, not fine grained permissions using RBAC

Answer (score 1):

If I got your point correctly that:

The IAM roles for a GKE kubernetes cluster are very simple, "Admin, Read/Write, Read".
But you need more fine-grained control over the kubernetes cluster.

**In this case:**

There's a new "Alpha" feature in Google Cloud's IAM which wasn't available previously.

**Under IAM > Roles**

You can now create custom IAM roles with your own subset of permissions.

You can create a minimal role which allows for example `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` to work, but nothing else, allowing permissions within the kubernetes cluster to be fully managed by RBAC.

It will allow you to get more fine-grained access configurations for kubernetes cluster.